How can I convert a json file to a pandas dataframe
I have a json file with this structure:
[
  {
    "name": "myName",
    "type": {
      "x": {
        "id": [
          "x1",
          "x2"
        ]
      },
      "y": {
        "id": "y1"
      },
      "z": {
        "id": "z1"
      }
    }
  }
]

Type can only take values x, y, and z. Any of those can be missing, but there is always at least one x, y, or z. There is no limit to the number of id's for each type, although there are never more than ten id-values in the data.
I would like to transform that into a Pandas dataframe, with structure:



Name
type
id




myName
x
x1


myName
x
x2


myName
y
y1


myName
z
z1



I've experimented with to_json{orient="..."} and json_normalize(), but I'm not able to flatten the lists in the json.

Can you have several items in the outmost list? It's unclear from your example how this generalizes

@mozway in my specific case, there is one file per name, but would be useful to know how to generalize.

Please try the answers below. I believe both should work in your case.

Assuming lst the input (as python object) and using a nested list comprehension:
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': d['name'], 'type': t, 'id': i}
                   for d in lst
                   for t, ids in d['type'].items()
                   for i in (ids['id'] if isinstance(ids['id'], list)
                             else [ids['id']])
                  ])

Output:
     name type  id
0  myName    x  x1
1  myName    x  x2
2  myName    y  y1
3  myName    z  z1

Which can be simplified using explode:
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': d['name'], 'type': t, 'id': ids['id']}
                   for d in lst
                   for t, ids in d['type'].items()
                  ]).explode('id')

Output:
     name type  id
0  myName    x  x1
0  myName    x  x2
1  myName    y  y1
2  myName    z  z1

Used input:
lst = [
  {
    "name": "myName",
    "type": {
      "x": {
        "id": [
          "x1",
          "x2"
        ]
      },
      "y": {
        "id": "y1"
      },
      "z": {
        "id": "z1"
      }
    }
  }
]


Works perfect, thanks! But can you explain a bit more how this works?

@Matthijs What is unclear to you? Are you familiar with dictionary comprehensions? This is a compact way to perform a loop (here a nested loop). The explode approach uses one less level of nesting and takes advantage of this function to unnest the last level (list or item).

I'm familiar with simple list comprehensions but this nested dictionary comprehension is slightly confusing...Thanks for the link, will study the syntax.

You should first create the rows, than convert those into DF:
data = json.loads(json_data)

def create_rows(data):
  rows = []
  for item in data:
    name = item['name']
    type_info = item['type']
    
    for type_key, type_value in type_info.items():
        ids = type_value['id']
        if not isinstance(ids, list):
            ids = [ids]
        for id_value in ids:
            rows.append({"name": name, "type": type_key, "id": id_value})
              
  return rows

rows = create_rows(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

Result:
|    | name   | type   | id   |
|---:|:-------|:-------|:-----|
|  0 | myName | x      | x1   |
|  1 | myName | x      | x2   |
|  2 | myName | y      | y1   |
|  3 | myName | z      | z1   |

